# oracle DB Why String having space comparison in gives false always?

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I am trying to compare the same strings having space and not having space
but all three comparison  operators ('>, <, =') are giving false output.

I first had assumption oracle string comparison is nonpadded.
please can any one explain am I missing on something?.

```
select case when 'a ' > 'a' then 't' else 'f' end from dual;
```

[image]

```
select case when 'a ' < 'a' then 't' else 'f' end from dual;
```

[image]

```
select case when 'a ' = 'a' then 't' else 'f' end from dual;
```

[image]

Comment: This must be a bug because in other contexts `'a ' = 'a'` is true. For example, `select * from dual where 'a ' = 'a'` returns one row. I know Oracle's (perhaps every vendor) SQL is not composable but this is simply unacceptable. It is unacceptable that comparison rules vary by context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TL;DR] To get it to work as expected, use `CAST` to give the literals an explicit data type. Something like either: `CAST('a ' AS VARCHAR2(10))` or `CAST('a ' AS CHAR(2))`.

---

There is something happening with the default literal data type and it appears to be a bug.

If you define a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data (lhs CHAR(2), rhs CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO data VALUES ('a ', 'a');
```

and then run:

```sql
select case when lhs > rhs then 't' else 'f' end AS gt_ch,
       case when lhs < rhs then 't' else 'f' end AS lt_ch,
       case when lhs = rhs then 't' else 'f' end AS eq_ch,
       case
       when lhs > rhs then 'gt'
       when lhs < rhs then 'lt'
       when lhs = rhs then 'eq'
       else NULL
       end AS comp,
       case
       when CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10)) > CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))
       then 't'
       else 'f'
       end AS gt_vc,
       case
       when CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10)) < CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))
       then 't'
       else 'f'
       end AS lt_vc,
       case
       when CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10)) = CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))
       then 't'
       else 'f'
       end AS eq_vc,
       DUMP(lhs) AS dmp_lsh_raw,
       DUMP(CAST(lhs AS CHAR(2))) AS dmp_lhs_ch,
       DUMP(CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10))) AS dmp_lhs_vc,
       DUMP(rhs) AS dmp_rsh_raw,
       DUMP(CAST(rhs AS CHAR(2))) AS dmp_rhs_ch,
       DUMP(CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))) AS dmp_rhs_vc
from   data;
```

Then the output is:

> | GT_CH | LT_CH | EQ_CH | COMP | GT_VC | LT_VC | EQ_VC | DMP_LSH_RAW | DMP_LHS_CH | DMP_LHS_VC | DMP_RSH_RAW | DMP_RHS_CH | DMP_RHS_VC |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | f | f | t | eq | t | f | f | Typ=96 Len=2: 97,32 | Typ=96 Len=2: 97,32 | Typ=1 Len=2: 97,32 | Typ=96 Len=1: 97 | Typ=96 Len=2: 97,32 | Typ=1 Len=1: 97 |

This works and comparing them as their default data-type of `CHAR`, using [Blank-Padding Comparison Semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-A114F1F4-A08D-4107-B679-323DC7FEA31C), then `'a '` and `'a'` are equal but comparing them as `VARCHAR2` data-types, using Non-Padded Comparison Semantics, then `'a '` is greater than `'a'`. This is the expected behaviour.

If you do the same query with literals explicitly cast to `CHAR` data types generated inside a sub-query factoring clause (a.k.a. CTE):

```sql
WITH cte (lhs, rhs) AS (
  SELECT CAST('a ' AS CHAR(2)),
         CAST('a' AS CHAR(1))
  FROM   DUAL
)
select case when lhs > rhs then 't' else 'f' end AS gt_ch,
       case when lhs < rhs then 't' else 'f' end AS lt_ch,
       case when lhs = rhs then 't' else 'f' end AS eq_ch,
       case
       when lhs > rhs then 'gt'
       when lhs < rhs then 'lt'
       when lhs = rhs then 'eq'
       else NULL
       end AS comp,
       case
       when CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10)) > CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))
       then 't'
       else 'f'
       end AS gt_vc,
       case
       when CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10)) < CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))
       then 't'
       else 'f'
       end AS lt_vc,
       case
       when CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10)) = CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))
       then 't'
       else 'f'
       end AS eq_vc,
       DUMP(lhs) AS dmp_lsh_raw,
       DUMP(CAST(lhs AS CHAR(2))) AS dmp_lhs_ch,
       DUMP(CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10))) AS dmp_lhs_vc,
       DUMP(rhs) AS dmp_rsh_raw,
       DUMP(CAST(rhs AS CHAR(2))) AS dmp_rhs_ch,
       DUMP(CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))) AS dmp_rhs_vc
from   cte;
```

Then the output is identical to when the data is stored in a table and, again, it is the expected behaviour.

However, if you remove the explicit casts and use the default data types for the literals:

```sql
WITH cte_default_data_type (lhs, rhs) AS (
  SELECT 'a ',
         'a'
  FROM   DUAL
)
select case when lhs > rhs then 't' else 'f' end AS gt_ch,
       case when lhs < rhs then 't' else 'f' end AS lt_ch,
       case when lhs = rhs then 't' else 'f' end AS eq_ch,
       case
       when lhs > rhs then 'gt'
       when lhs < rhs then 'lt'
       when lhs = rhs then 'eq'
       else NULL
       end AS comp,
       case
       when CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10)) > CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))
       then 't'
       else 'f'
       end AS gt_vc,
       case
       when CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10)) < CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))
       then 't'
       else 'f'
       end AS lt_vc,
       case
       when CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10)) = CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))
       then 't'
       else 'f'
       end AS eq_vc,
       DUMP(lhs) AS dmp_lsh_raw,
       DUMP(CAST(lhs AS CHAR(2))) AS dmp_lhs_ch,
       DUMP(CAST(lhs AS VARCHAR2(10))) AS dmp_lhs_vc,
       DUMP(rhs) AS dmp_rsh_raw,
       DUMP(CAST(rhs AS CHAR(2))) AS dmp_rhs_ch,
       DUMP(CAST(rhs AS VARCHAR2(10))) AS dmp_rhs_vc
from   cte_default_data_type;
```

Then the output is:

> | GT_CH | LT_CH | EQ_CH | COMP | GT_VC | LT_VC | EQ_VC | DMP_LSH_RAW | DMP_LHS_CH | DMP_LHS_VC | DMP_RSH_RAW | DMP_RHS_CH | DMP_RHS_VC |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | f | f | f | eq | t | f | f | Typ=96 Len=2: 97,32 | Typ=96 Len=2: 97,32 | Typ=1 Len=2: 97,32 | Typ=96 Len=1: 97 | Typ=96 Len=2: 97,32 | Typ=1 Len=1: 97 |

And none of the first 3 `CASE` expressions are true (as found in the question). However, the output from `DUMP` is identical to the previous queries.

This should not happen as the values should either be compared as `CHAR` data types, in which case Blank-Padding Comparison Semantics should apply, or compared as `VARCHAR2` data types, in which case Non-Padded Comparison Semantics should apply, and in this case it appears to be using something else and is not following either rule and is not the expected behaviour.

To work around it, use `CAST` to give the literal an explicit data-type as this appears to "fix" the issue.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c3deb5adc5a7af49c178990d4771ac93)*

Answer (score 1):

When character strings are compared, there are two options:

- Blank-Padded Comparison Semantics

  > If the two values have different lengths, then Oracle first adds blanks to the end of the shorter one so their lengths are equal. Oracle then compares the values character by character up to the first character that differs
- Nonpadded comparison semantics

See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm).

If all 3 cases you posted are put into the same `case` expression, this is the result:

```
SQL> select case when 'a ' > 'a' then 't1'
  2              when 'a ' < 'a' then 'f2'
  3              when 'a ' = 'a' then 'f3'
  4              else 'x4'
  5         end query_1
  6  from dual;

QU
--
f3

SQL>
```

`f3`? It says they are **equal** because of the blank-padded comparison (described above).